# How to use truncate table and insert into table in user define function for SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm trying to use a simple function in SQL server 2005 and it generates an error.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_data_stat_cc_update]
(
  @result char
)
RETURNS char(1)
AS
  BEGIN
    truncate table stg_data_cancer_center;

    INSERT INTO stg_data_cancer_center(
            mrn, pt_city, pt_state, pt_zip, pt_pri_dx, clinic, source
    SELECT rtrim(ltrim(mrn)) as mrn,
    pat_city, pat_state, zipcode, exact_icd9_code_pri_dx, 'clinic' =
    case
        when inst_id = 1 then 'CANRAD'
        when inst_id = 2 then 'CANHAM'
        else @result--''
    end, 'MOSAIQ' as Source
    from stg_mosaiq_patient;

     RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@result)) 
  END
```

Errors are:

```
Procedure fn_data_stat_cc_update, Line 18
Invalid use of side-effecting or time-dependent operator in 'TRUNCATE TABLE' within a function.
Procedure fn_data_stat_cc_update, Line 25
Invalid use of side-effecting or time-dependent operator in 'INSERT' within a function.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

You need to use a stored procedure. Functions are not allowed to have side effects such as modifying data.

Comment: Thank you, Martin. I'll create a stor proc.